# What is the difference between string declaration and setting string as null?

Tags: c#

I know it is kind of dumb question, but still want to know exactly what the difference is between these two (I understand the difference of string a = "" and string a = null):

```
string a; 
string a = null;
```

Comment: If they are local variables, one of these two is "definitely assigned". One is not. If they are fields... the `null` assignment is redundant

Comment: Why is he being punished for not knowing the c# language as the experts on SO?

Comment: Your comment says you want to know the difference between a = "" and a = null, but your code sample depicts the difference between non-assignment and assignment.  An assignment of empty string is different from not assigning the variable at all.

Comment: I think you misread (?). his title states "difference between string decl and setting null. his explanation states that he does understand the diff between = "" and = null. but he doesn't understand the diff between decl and init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the scope of the said declaration: in the local scope, the first variable is unassigned, while the second variable is assigned:

```
void foo() {
    string a;
    if (CheckUserInput()) {
        a = "Bar";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(a); // << Error
}
```

vs.

```
void foo() {
    string a = null;
    if (CheckUserInput()) {
        a = "Bar";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(a); // << Correct
}
```

At the class scope, there is no difference:

```
class X {
    string a;
}

class Y {
    string a = null;
}
```

In both cases `a` starts off as `null`.

Comment: This answer is really I am look for. Comes to the point. Other people' answer are also very good. Sorry cannot choose more than one correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

For local variables, the first form is just *declaring* a variable, the second is *declaring and assigning*. Most operations on a variable, like calling a method with an input parameter, or returning from a method, require that the variable used as a parameter is *assigned*.

```
string a;
MethodThatTakesAString(a); // compile time error: use of unassigned local variable 'a' !
```

Note that an `out` parameter doesn't have that requirement, the compiler considers `a` to be assigned after the method call:

```
string a;
MethodThatGivesAString(out a);
```

Some more info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The first line just declares a string but leaves it uninitialized. If you attempt to use that string, e.g.:

```
string b = a + " says howdy";
```

...you'll get a compile error telling you that you're trying to use an uninitialized variable.

The second line however, initializes the variable to a value (null, which is really an identifier that means "no value", but in a different way. At least the compiler knows that you're explicitly saying "hey, this variable has no value" instead of just leaving it up in the air.)

Comment: It would be more accurate to say null is a value, but it refers to no object.

Comment: @EricLippert How do you unravel that thread when asked about `int? foo = null; var hasValue = foo.HasValue;` then? ;)

Comment: OK, it would be more accurate to say that *the null reference* is a value, but it refers to no object. The null value of a value type is also a value, but it is not a reference in the first place.